# Horrible Frame drops on Black ops 3 Zombies

Tags: technical-issues, call-of-duty-black-ops-3

After more or less 10 minutes of playing, my graphics card seems to be creating strange anomalies across the screen. I tried updating my Display Drivers. And also installing older drivers. I am thinking then it might an actual ingame issue.

My GPU is the Radeon R9 270

I am not sure what else to adjust in the game itself, at the moment all my settings are set to low. with 1920 x 1080 resolution and runs between 80 - 100 fps normally. When the anomalies start to appear my frames drops to 2 fps and then stays there.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot showing those anomalies? Sounds like your GPU is dying, though.

Comment: Aaahh @Nolonar I can confirm my Gpu is officially dead. :(

Answer (score 1):

My GPU died. It was the hardware failure causing the anomalies.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a Q&A style post? Or is it just you finding the solution?

Comment: @Kaizerwolf it's clearly the solution?